# Writing function that calculates rowwise mean for subset of columns and creates column name

Tags: r, function, tidyr, startswith, rowwise

I want to turn this line of code into a function:

```
mutate(var_avg = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("var"))))
```

It works in the pipe:

```
df <- read_csv("var_one,var_two,var_three
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3")

df %>% mutate(var_avg = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("var"))))

># A tibble: 3 x 4
>  var_one var_two var_three var_avg
>    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
>1       1       1         1       1
>2       2       2         2       2
>3       3       3         3       3
```

Here's my attempt (I'm new at writing functions):

```
colnameMeans <- function(x) {
  columnname <- paste0("avg_",x)
  mutate(columnname <- rowMeans(select(., starts_with(x))))
}
```

It doesn't work.

```
df %>% colnameMeans("var")
>Error in colnameMeans(., "var") : unused argument ("var")
```

I have a lot to learn about functions and I'm not sure where to start with fixing this. Any help would be much appreciated. Note that this is a simplified example. In my real data, I have several column prefixes and I want to calculate a row-wise mean for each one. EDIT: Being able to run the function for multiple prefixes at once would be a bonus.

Comment: What does !!columnname := do differently? I am getting the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to assign column name on the lhs of assignment, use `:=` and evaluate (`!!`) the string.  The `<-` inside `mutate` won't work as the default option is `=` and it would evaluate unquoted value on the lhs of `=` literally.  In addition, we may need to specify the data as argument in the function

```
library(dplyr)
colnameMeans <- function(., x) { 
   columnname<- paste0("avg_", x)
   mutate(., !! columnname := rowMeans(select(., starts_with(x))))
  }
df %>% 
  colnameMeans('var')
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  var_one var_two var_three avg_var
#    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#1       1       1         1       1
#2       2       2         2       2
#3       3       3         3       3
```

---

If there are several prefixes, use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
colnameMeans <- function(., x) { 
   columnname<- paste0("avg_", x)
   transmute(., !! columnname := rowMeans(select(., starts_with(x))))
  }


map_dfc(c('var', 'alt'), ~ df1 %>%
        colnameMeans(.x)) %>%
      bind_cols(df1, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  var_one var_two var_three alt_var_one alt_var_two alt_var_three avg_var avg_alt
#*   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1       1       1         1           1           1             1       1       1
#2       2       2         2           2           2             2       2       2
#3       3       3         3           3           3             3       3       3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- bind_cols(df,  df %>% rename_all(~ str_replace(., 'var_', 'new_')))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Sorry to move the goalposts, but do you know how to get it to simultaneously accept multiple strings as input?
For example, 
df %>% colnameMeans("var", "alt_var")

Comment: Thank you for this additional info! I noticed that the map_dfc code block doesn't work in the pipe but has to be run on its own. Is that correct?

Comment: @SusieDerkins not clear about your comment.   If you do `c('var', 'alt') %>% map_dfc(., ~ df1 %>%..` it should work.